# Correlation between combinations of uncorrelated variables

Tags: correlation

If I have uncorrelated variables X,Y,Z how do I find the correlation between (X+Y) & (Y+Z)?

Ps. It's a theory question: ie, I can't compute the correlation from observed instances of X,Y & Z. What I can do is assume these variables have a standard deviation of a,b & c, and figure out the correlation of M & N (where M=X+Y & N=Y+Z) from there.

Comment: Coul you specify in your question what you mean by "and so on"? + maybe you could first simply compute the covariance between $X+Y$ and $Y+Z$ and see where it goes...

Comment: Edited the question. Essentially, I need to know how to compute covariance between (X+Y) & (Y+Z) given sd of X,Y & Z.

Comment: Hint: Covariance is a _bilinear_ function meaning that \begin{align}\operatorname{cov}(aW+bX,cY+dZ) &= (ac)\cdot\operatorname{cov}(W,Y)+(bd)\cdot\operatorname{cov}(X,Z)\\& ~~+(ad)\cdot\operatorname{cov}(W,Z)+(bc)\cdot\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)\end{align} unless, of course, those $\&$'s mean something else.

Comment: Ok, I did not mean "compute" with a calculator, I meant: write down the definition of the correlation, or maybe first of the covariance, expand and simplify the terms that go away thanks to your hypotheses, and see what is left.

Comment: @DilipSarwate. Thanks! I had forgotten that property, and it is definitely what I needed.

Comment: @VincentGuillemot Thanks Vincent. While I'd tried the expansion (16 terms), it has left me with terms I was unable to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

Use bilinearity and calculate 
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\cov}{\mathbb{C}ov}
   \DeclareMathOperator{\var}{\mathbb{V}ar}
   \DeclareMathOperator{\cor}{corr}
\cov(X+Y,Y+Z) =\cov(X,Y)+\cov(X,Z)+\cov(Y,Y)+\cov(Y,Z) =0+0+\var(Y)+0
$$
so 
$$
 \cor(X+Y,Y+Z)=\frac{\cov(X+Y,Y+Z)}{\sqrt{\var(X+Y) \var(Y+Z)}} = \\
\frac{\var(Y)}{\sqrt{(\var(X)+\var(Y))(\var(Y)+\var(Z))}}
$$
and you can take it from there.